# pluralizing composite nouns or phrase nouns?

Tags: grammar

How do you pluralize them?

Example:

> There were two Sonic The Hedgehogs next to each other.

> There were two Sonic The Hedgehog next to each other.

We're talking about identical clones. Is there a better way? It looks weird to me.

Comment: This is why you don't do that. You'd say something like "I saw Sonic - actually, two of him. There were two Sonics, side by side."

Comment: Sonic Hedgehogs, aren't they??

Comment: I see two identical sentences next to each other. I see two identical sentences next to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[When pluralizing compound nouns](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/plurals_forming_compound_nouns.htm), we normally pluralize the principal word, for example,
**mother**-in-law -> **mothers**-in-law

But *Sonic the Hedgehog* isn't a compound noun, it's a proper name, and when pluralizing proper names, you pluralize the whole thing.  For example,

> It is estimated that there are almost 48,000 **John Smiths** around the U.S., more than any other name. There are also, interestingly, more than a thousand **James Bonds**.

(source: https://247wallst.com/special-report/2019/09/04/famous-people-with-the-same-names/)

Therefore the most reasonable answer is that the plural is actually **Sonic the Hedgehogs**.

Comment: Why mention pluralizing compound nouns if it doesn't apply?

Comment: @gotube  Because the OP mentioned composite nouns, but I wanted to point out the difference.